# Testing if point inside multipolygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon, point, point-in-polygon

How do I know if a point (or a coordinate lon-lat) is inside of a MULTIPOLYGON using PostGIS?

I tried with `ST_Contains()`, but being a MULTIPOLYGON always return False.

Also I tried with `ST_Dump()` for transform to a simple POLYGON but I didn't get that to work.

I used:

```sql
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(the_geom,900913)
```

and then:

```sql
SELECT ST_Contains("previous select result", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326))
```

Comment: Did you actually create a new table with single part polygons using ST_Dump?

Comment: Make sure your geometries are valid

Comment: I use:  SELECT ST_GeomFromText(the_geom,900913), and next: SELECT ST_Contains("previous select result", ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT(lon lat)\',4326))

Comment: Please *edit* the question to include  clarifications. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: ST_Contains will always return false when the point and polygon do not share a coordinate system.  You need to project (ST_Transform) one or the other (or both, thought that seems wasteful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the point and the shape are not projected to the same coordinate system; one or the other needs to be converted, using `ST_Transform()` like this:

```
SELECT ST_Contains('the_geom',ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon lat)',4326),900913))
```

Thanks to [Vince](/users/21577) for the hint.